# Can I use a sequential key binding like Ctrl-x Ctrl-s in Sublime Text?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2, sublime-text

I'm trying out Sublime Text.  I've been an Emacs (in Evil mode) user for several years.  As a result I have Ctrl-x Ctrl-s for save deeply embedded in my muscle memory (so deeply embedded that I sometimes accidentally use it in the shell when I've finished a long command :) ), but there doesn't seem to be any way to ask Sublime to use multiple key presses (as opposed to the more standard Ctrl and Ctrl-Alt combinations) for a command.  Is there a way this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to answer the main question of how to assign multiple key combinations to a command: Open **`Preferences -> Key Bindings-User`** and, if the file is empty, add the following:

```js
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+x", "ctrl+s"], "command": "save" }
]
```

To add additional key bindings, just put a comma `,` after the closing curly brace `}` and add your new binding on the next line - essentially, the file has to be valid [JSON](http://json.org). A list of all bindable keys can be found [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#bindable-keys), and the rest of that page contains all sorts of good information on key bindings.

Comment: Ah, I should have RTFM.  You're right, this is the actual answer to my question, even though David Postill's answer is more helpful to me.  After agonising over it, am switching the accept flag to this answer :).

Comment: @ShankarG thanks! David's answer is quite useful, I've used the package when I get a hankering to relive my old emacs days (I actually use vim more now when I'm SSHing into a server). I'm glad we could both help solve your problem!

Answer (score 2):

**Reference** [Making Sublime Text more Emacs awesome](https://github.com/grundprinzip/sublemacspro) :

> The reasoning behind writing these set of functions is that we love
>   Emacs, however, the UI doesn't feel as snappy as other Mac apps. On
>   the other hand we cannot move to another editor since many of those
>   hyped editors share that they don't provide the keybindings we love
>   and embraced over time.
>
> Then, we found Sublime Text. A completely customizable editor allowing
>   you to easily modify all default behaviors so that they suit your
>   editing style.
>
> So, **we wrote sublemacspro bringing Emacs keybindings and sugar to
>   Sublime Text.** Even though Emacs lives from the plugins, we believe it
>   is way easier to write new plugins in Python and integrate them in an
>   Emacs-ish way to Sublime Text than writing them in Lisp.

...

> **The main development for Sublemacs is now Sublime Text 3 only.
>   However, there is still the branch using the earlier codebase for ST2.**
>
> https://github.com/grundprinzip/sublemacspro/tree/st2

...

> **most likely a key binding that you expect from Emacs will work as well in sublemacs**